# Ajax control toolkit Rating Control- Override RatingBehavior.js

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

Rating control in Ajax control toolkit will not raise the event if a user clicks on current rating star because in behaviour js it has checked
`if (this._ratingValue != this._currentRating)`, so I want to override this method without changing js and building toolkit. How can I do it, can I extend rating control and override `RatingBehavior.js` or any other solution.

```
_onStarClick : function(e) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for a star's click event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e" type="Sys.UI.DomEvent">
    /// Event info
    /// </param>
    if (this._readOnly) {
        return;
    }
    if (this._ratingValue != this._currentRating) {
        this.set_Rating(this._currentRating);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it by putting the code just above

```
    function AddNewRatingHandler() {

        AjaxControlToolkit.RatingBehavior.prototype._onStarClick =
            function(e) {
                if (this._readOnly) {
                    return;
                }
                //   if (this._ratingValue != this._currentRating) {                    
                this.set_Rating(this._currentRating);
                // }
            };
            AjaxControlToolkit.RatingBehavior.prototype.set_Rating = function(value) {                    
                //   if (this._ratingValue != value) {
                this._ratingValue = value;
                this._currentRating = value;
                if (this.get_isInitialized()) {
                    if ((value < 0) || (value > this._maxRatingValue)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    this._update();

                    AjaxControlToolkit.RatingBehavior.callBaseMethod(this, 'set_ClientState', [this._ratingValue]);
                    this.raisePropertyChanged('Rating');
                    this.raiseRated(this._currentRating);
                    this._waitingMode(true);

                    var args = this._currentRating + ";" + this._tag;
                    var id = this._callbackID;

                    if (this._autoPostBack) {
                        __doPostBack(id, args);
                    }
                    else {
                        WebForm_DoCallback(id, args, this._receiveServerData, this, this._onError, true)
                    }

                }
                //  }
            };                
    }
    AddNewRatingHandler();

</script>



</div>

</form>
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there anything else i need to do besides adding this code to my aspx page?